# Вопросы по верстке - по БЭМ

Tags: css, вёрстка, бэм

Привет.

Вопросы по верстке по БЭМ.

1. Написано в документации, что "Блок не должен влиять на свое окружение, т. е. блоку не следует задавать внешнюю геометрию (в виде отступов, границ, влияющих на размеры) и позиционирование." Как же тогда задавать те же паддинги, маргины...?
2. Зачем нужен микс. Не понимаю. Есть блок, есть модификатор. Зачем еще микс? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример понятный.

Answer (score 10):

1. Идея в том, чтобы блок можно было повторно использовать в любом другом месте на странице (или даже на другом проекте).

   Если известно, что независимо от того, где данный блок потребуется, он будет иметь одинаковую высоту, ширину и рамку, то `width`, `height` и `border` можно смело оставлять.
   А вот `margin`, `position` и `float` с большой долей вероятности будет плохой идеей — нет гарантий, что в другом месте блок по-прежнему будет требовать таких же отступов и позиционирования. Разумеется бывают исключения, универсальное правило — руководствоваться здравым смыслом.
2. Прием, позволяющий использовать разные БЭМ-сущности на одном DOM-узле.

   Миксы позволяют:

   - Совмещать поведение и стили нескольких сущностей без дублирования кода;
   - Создавать семантически новые компоненты интерфейса на основе имеющихся.

   Пример микса:

   ```
   <!-- Блок `header` -->
   <div class="header">
       <!-- К блоку `search-form` примиксован элемент `search-form` блока `header`-->
       <div class="search-form header__search-form"></div>
   </div>
   ```

   В данном примере мы совместили поведение и стили блока `search-form` и элемента `search-form` блока `header`. Такой подход позволяет нам задать внешнюю геометрию и позиционирование в элементе `header__search-form`, а сам блок `search-form` оставить универсальным. Таким образом, блок можно использовать в любом другом окружении, потому что он не специфицирует никакие отступы. Это позволяет нам говорить о его независимости.

Простейшая реализация:

```css
/*
Вообразим что это прекрасный блок формы
Он может быть переиспользован в другом месте, но вид у него дефолтно такой
*/
.search-form{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0,149,255,1);
  color: #00ff5c;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

/*
Вообразим что это прекрасный блок шапки
Он знать ничего не знает о других блоках, однако, его элементы должны приводить содержимое в нужную форму
*/
.header{
  color: blue;
}

/*
Элемент формы шапки
Он не знает про блок формы, но знает что в шапке у формы должен быть margin от текста ниже формы
И плавная смена цвета при наведении
*/
.header__search-form{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all .5s;
}
.header__search-form:hover{
  background: #0e13b5;
}
```

```html
<!-- Блок `header` -->
<div class="header">
  <!-- К блоку `search-form` примиксован элемент `search-form` блока `header`-->
  <div class="search-form header__search-form">Форма</div>
  <div>Это шапка</div>
</div>
```

Comment: так как же тогда задавать margin, position и float для блока?

Comment: @Dimon, через стили :) БЭМ говорит не трогать блоки, но добавить стили для конкретных случаев никто не запрещал.

Comment: не понял этот ответ. можешь пример привести?

Comment: @Dimon, обновил.