# Какие свойства нужно прописывать для каждого из типов БЭМ?

Tags: бэм

Здравствуйте! У меня несколько вопросов по БЭМ, которые не дают покоя... Я неоднократно встречался с мнением, что блоку нельзя давать размеры. То есть получается, что ни один из блоков я не могу передвинуть (чуть-чуть) с помощью margin. Не могу задать padding и ширину? Отсюда вопрос: Какие свойства нужно прописывать каждому из типу БЭМ... Блоку, Элементу, Модификатору?

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: Вот вариант ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/641071/208926